# How to use NOT IN with the Union Result

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the distinct values from one table having different conditions.

The Query that I am using is

```
Select A.* 
from A
 where A.x not in (select B.x from B 
                   union
                   select C.x from C
                  )
```

Please note that I have been using CTE to get the different values.

When I standalone run this `select B.x from B union select C.x from C` 
I see the output.
Same goes for table A also.

But when I run it together I see no data.

Comment: Do you have any `null`s in your `union` result? `null`s kill `not in` queries.

Comment: Normally you would do that like this: `select a.* from a left join b onb.x = a.x left join c on c.x = a.x where b.x is null and c.x is null`

Comment: If my sub query has nulls, will coalesce function help me with this

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are rows in `A` which do not have a matching value from `B+C`? Can you provide some sample?

Comment: HI Kamli, I am not sure exactly how to make a table in stack over flow. This would be my first question here.

Comment: Use the "null-safe" `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`!

Comment: To format properly: When editing, put one empty row before the block of sample data, and put 4 <space> characters first in each row with sample data.

Comment: Table A has all the values for column x. but What I want is to select only those values from column x that are not used before (The Subquery has values for x that are already used once)

Comment: Thank you All for the response. It Worked out for me by using "not exists" and "left outer join".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with tabletemporary
AS 
( 
    SELECT b.x AS name from b UNION SELECT c.x AS name FROM c
)
Select a.* FROM a WHERE a.x NOT IN
          (SELECT name FROM tabletemporary)
```

**you can use this code**

Comment: I cannot use this since I guess we cannot perform nested CTE. I have already used that table and the conditions are different in the main query. But this would have been way easier if my requirements were not that complex.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `not exists`

```
Select A.* from A where 
not exists (select 1 from b where b.x = A.x)
and
not exists (select 1 from c where c.x = A.x)
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff  -   I agree, `where b.x = A.x` is more cleaner.